# What happens to Node* next when deleting that Node in a linked list?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

In a linked list that uses

```
struct Node {
  T value;
  Node* next; 
}
```

For every used *new* operator `(new Node())`, there must be a *delete* operator.
An example of a destructor for such a list

```
~LinkedList(){ 
   Node* tmp = head;
   while(tmp! = nullptr){
     delete tmp;
     tmp = tmp->next;
   }
 }
```

My question is, what exactly gets "deleted" that allows me to use *next* pointer
even after *delete* is used? Does it only delete the value? How does that actually look in the memory?

Comment: delete is accompanied with a move. The next element of the previous item in the linked list is now pointing to the element after the deleted one.

Comment: There is an error in your code. If you call `delete tmp` then in tmp->next you will get Access Violation or something like this

Comment: `tmp->next` after `delete tmp` _may_ happen to work sometimes, but this is strictly undefined behavior.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis Not in this code.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis `delete` is *not* accompanied by a move, and none of the rest of your comment takes place in this code. What are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ when you delete an object on the heap nothing actually gets cleaned up, it just marks the memory as "free". This means that another call to `new` or `malloc` may overwrite that memory.

Accessing a deleted pointer is undefined behaviour because their are no guarantees on the data that resides there. I'm not very well versed in how the OS handles memory but I believe it could even be the case that your program no longer owns that page if that was the last item you deleted from that section of memory. If this happened to be the case then dereferencing that pointer will cause a segmentation fault on most desktop OS's.

If you wanted to safely move the head you should assign a temporary value to the next item while the pointer is alive, then you can delete the underlying object from memory.

Answer (score 0):

When a data is deleted the pointer becomes undefined and for sure does not reach to memory it was pointing before, therefore there is no way to call `tmp=tmp->next'` after deletion.

The proper destructor declaration would be:

```
~LinkedList()
{
    while (head != nullptr)
    {
        Node * tmp = head->next;
        delete head;
        head = tmp;
    }
}
```

BTW.: Please read some good books on how to implement lists.

BTW.2: Use some standard containers like `vector` or `list` if you really need it.

Comment: C++ does not do memory bounds checking or validation before dereferencing a pointer. If their was valid memory there before, as long as the application still owns that page of memory, it can be dereferenced. When the data at that location no longer represents a valid object (has been overwritten) then you will most likely get errors due to the resulting reads/writes that occur on memory outside of the original object due to any internal pointers now being completely different data.

Comment: The pointer does not "become undefined"; and for sure it points to the same memory that it pointed to before. The problem is that this memory is now deallocated, and so it might get overwritten at any time, or even mapped out of the user's address space. The OP's code will probably work most of the time.